# método para fazer login usando DataSnap

Tags: mysql, delphi, login, datasnap

Estou fazendo uma aplicação Android usando Delphi, tenho um servidor com os métodos para pegar os dados do Banco de dados Mysql, gostaria de saber como posso fazer um método para pegar os usuários que já estão cadastrados no banco de dados e depois como chamar esse método na aplicação, assim quando o usuário abrir o aplicativo no celular ele irá fazer o login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa primeiramente criar os métodos do Datasnap para o Android e colocar na sua aplicação, exemplo:

```
C:\Win32ProxyDownloader.exe -language java_android -host 127.0.0.1:8080 -output C:\test
```

Depois você cria uma classe com uma conexão Datasnap para se conectar ao servidor:

```
DSRESTConnection conn = new DSRESTConnection();
conn.setHost("host");
conn.setPort(port);
conn.setProtocol("http");
```

E para recuperar os dados:

```
TServerMethods1 proxy = new TServerMethods1(conn);
VarParamTestReturns Result = proxy.VarParamTest("Hello, World!");
System.out.println(Result.Value);
System.out.println(Result.returnValue);
```

Sendo esse o método criado na aplicação DataSnap do lado do servidor geralmente declarado no arquivo `DServerMethods.pas` da aplicação:

```
function TServerMethods1.VarParamTest(var Value: string): string;
begin
  Value := StrUtils.ReverseString(Value);
  Result := Value;
end;
```

Referências:

[Developing DataSnap Applications](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Developing_DataSnap_Applications)

[Getting Started with Java Android DataSnap Mobile Connector](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Getting_Started_with_Java_Android_DataSnap_Mobile_Connector)